# How to add simple onchange events on Angular 2 components

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the component file and its templateURL html file.

In the html file I have the following code:

```
 <input type="range" min="0" max="20" value="0" step="1" change="showValue(this.value)" />
    <span id="range">0</span>
```

In the component, I have this code:

```
ngAfterviewInit(){
    function showValue(newValue){
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
    }
}
```

I put the function in there, but it says its not defined. I am not sure how to define the function, and how to call it in the html file.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance, I'm quite new to A2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **ngmodel** to bind your value and bind the same to span.No need to define any new functions.Please see below.

```
 <input type="range" min="0" max="20" [(ngModel)]="variable" step="1"  />
 <span id="range">{{variable}}</span>
```

you need to declare **variable** at component side.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-app="">
<input type="range" min="0" max="20" value="0" step="1" ng-model="rangenumber" />
<span ng-bind="rangenumber" id="range">0</span>
</div>
```

Component events Read this article https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2

Comment: it is angularjs syntax

Comment: You wrote an answer using AngularJs syntax and linked an *Angular* post..

Comment: The question is about Angular2 (not angularjs / v1)